# connect dots to a rectangle with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

i detected color from image using opencv, but now i don't know how to make a rectangle from the dots, look at the images for example. i tried looking on the internet but i couldn't find any answer. please help me i am trying forever, i tried many things but nothing worked. all im trying to do is to make a rectangle around each of these dots.

[what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j92Xz.png)

[what i want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03jax.png)

Comment: morphology operations.

Comment: Can you explain further?